# React - Re-render child component when parent state is updated

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a list of numbers from lowest to highest and on load of my component I display those numbers in a list. I have a function to sort the numbers highest to lowest that I run on click of a button and update the state. I can log out the new state and see that the numbers have been sorted from highest to lowest, but how do I now update my child component which displays the list to reflect this change??

Parent:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <List data={this.state.numbers} />
      <button onClick={this.reorder}>Reorder</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child:

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props.data)
  return (
    <div className="community-list">
      {this.props.data && this.props.data.map((value, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{value}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

## [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-banzai-tfoip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mutate the state as this can cause this sort of bugs when the reference is not changing and child component will bail out from re-rendering due to React reference checks.

Also when you update the state you have to call `this.setState(/* nextState */)`

Your array is already sorted so it won't reflect the changes, change the order of the elements to see the state change

```js
reorder = () => {
  // make a copy of the current numbers array using slice, then freely mutate it
  // before setting the new state
  const reorderedNumbers = this.state.numbers.slice().sort()
  this.setState({ numbers: reorderedNumbers })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another way:

```
reorder = () => {    
    this.setState(state=>
      ({
        numbers: state.numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a)
      }),(()=>{
        console.log(this.state.numbers);
      })
      );    
  };
```